# Elasticsearch timeout

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

In which scenario can I get an error like this?

The elastic search service is on the same computer as the client calling it, so there it no network issue. The server has free memory, free disk, and there is always at least 15-20% cpu free.

I'm inserting a lot of data in elastic, but it never came with a timeout; and today, there are hundreds of similar error in our logs.
Could it be because there are a lot of requests in parallel? the insertion code is heavily multi-threaded.

```
InternalServerError - Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /albums/albummetadata/f3c20bb7-8f60-5d80-fe87-449bdf3d828a/_update
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:01:00.3240283
 - [2] MaxTimeoutReached: Took: -736395.18:15:40.4144464
# OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TReturn](RequestData requestData) in C:\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\HttpConnection.cs:line 145
# Request:

# Response:

+The operation has timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing bulk inserts? Are your documents large?

It sounds reasonable that under heavy load inserts may timeout. You could try to detect increased error rates and scale back/slow down your insertions. You could also increase the timeout threshold, but that'll likely only go so far - you'll still end up with a backlog of requests that is ever-growing and will eventually start failing again.

Another option is to scale up your ES cluster, either increasing the specs of your current nodes or adding more nodes.

Comment: documents are fairly small (200-300 bytes each), but there is a large number of them (we're talking millions). inserts are done in bulk, but the failure actually occurs when editing the documents where a flag can get changed on a large number of documents at once which is why I'm surprised. The same change happens in parallel on our mongodb without any problem

Comment: "when editing the documents where a flag can get changed on a large number of documents at once"  

Are you using the Update or Update By Query? Updates will require the document to be reindexed and an Update By Query can cause a huge number of documents requiring to be reindexed.  

Are you monitoring load and index rates through Marvel or similar tools?

Comment: I have this call: Driver.Update<TObject, TUpdate>(Id, _ => _.Doc(Update)) where Update is just the field I'm changing. In short I need to make a large number of documents online / offline quickly, so there is a flag for this. I don't use monitoring tools at all

Comment: If you're running Elasticsearch 1 or 2, look into Marvel. If you're running 5, look into X-Pack > Monitoring. It is 100% free (the other bells and whistles requires a subscription - but not required for this). You will be able to view where your bottleneck is when you're experiencing your timeouts.

Comment: I don’t recall the details but I think the solution was to do smaller batches, which is not a true solution but it works